# RSA_Verify fails returns Bad signature error

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

I can't get the message verified after signing it.

I'm writing a project to simulate signing and verifying data from files with OpenSSL.
the signing process seems to work great, but on the verification process RSA_Verify always return 0. which is not verified.
I can't get it. what am I missing here?

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/applink.c>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define PRIKEY_FILENAME "private"
#define PUBKEY_FILENAME "public"

using namespace std;
typedef struct _INFO
{
    unsigned char *sig;
    unsigned int nLen;
}INFO, *pINFO;

bool ReadFileContent(string fileName,  char** out, size_t  &nLen)
{
    if (NULL == out)
        return false;

    ifstream file(fileName, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        nLen = (int)file.tellg();
        *out = new char[nLen];
        file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        file.read(*out, nLen);

        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file \"" << fileName << " \"\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool WriteFileContent(const char* data, int nLen, string fileName)
{
    if (NULL == data)
        return false;

    ofstream file(fileName, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.write(data, nLen);
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file \"" << fileName << " \"\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool GenerateKeyPairs()
{
    int             ret = 0;
    RSA             *r = NULL;
    BIGNUM          *bne = NULL;
    BIO             *bp_public = NULL, *bp_private = NULL;

    int             bits = 2048;
    unsigned long   e = RSA_F4;

    // 1. generate rsa key
    bne = BN_new();
    ret = BN_set_word(bne, e);
    if (ret != 1)
    {
        goto free_all;
    }

    r = RSA_new();
    ret = RSA_generate_key_ex(r, bits, bne, NULL);
    if (ret != 1)
    {
        goto free_all;
    }

    // 2. save public key
    bp_public = BIO_new_file(PUBKEY_FILENAME, "w+");
    ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(bp_public, r);
    if (ret != 1)
    {
        goto free_all;
    }

    // 3. save private key
    bp_private = BIO_new_file(PRIKEY_FILENAME, "w+");
    ret = PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bp_private, r, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // 4. free
free_all:

    BIO_free_all(bp_public);
    BIO_free_all(bp_private);
    RSA_free(r);
    BN_free(bne);

    return (ret == 1);
}

bool DoSign(string priKeyFile, pINFO pInfo, string fileName)
{
    int     ret;
    unsigned char* data = NULL;
    unsigned char* encodedData = NULL;
    size_t  nFileSize = 0;

    unsigned int nEncodedDataLen = 0;
    RSA* priKey = NULL;
    FILE* fp = NULL;

    if (!ReadFileContent(fileName, (char**)&data, nFileSize))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (data == NULL || nFileSize <= 0)
        return false;

    //SHA512(data, nFileSize, pInfo->sig);
    fp = fopen(PRIKEY_FILENAME, "r");
    priKey = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp, &priKey, NULL, NULL);

    pInfo->sig = (unsigned char*)malloc(RSA_size(priKey));
    /* Sign */
    ret = RSA_sign(NID_sha512, data, nFileSize, pInfo->sig, &pInfo->nLen, priKey);

    WriteFileContent((char*)pInfo->sig, pInfo->nLen, fileName + ".sign");

    return true;
}

bool DoVerify(string pubKeyFile, pINFO pInfo, string fileName)
{
    int ret = 0;
    unsigned char* data = NULL;
    unsigned char* encodedData = NULL;
    size_t  nFileSize = 0;
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    RSA* pubkey = NULL;

    unsigned int nEncodedDataLen = 0;

    if (!ReadFileContent(fileName, (char**)&data, nFileSize))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (data == NULL || nFileSize <= 0)
        return false;

    fp = fopen(PUBKEY_FILENAME, "r");
    pubkey = PEM_read_RSAPublicKey(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    ret = RSA_verify(NID_sha512, data, nFileSize, pInfo->sig, pInfo->nLen, pubkey);
    char buf[512];
    ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), buf);
    //Error here says bad signature
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    INFO info = { 0 };
    GenerateKeyPairs();
    DoSign(PRIKEY_FILENAME, &info, "Hello.txt");
    DoVerify(PUBKEY_FILENAME, &info, "Hello.txt.sign");
    return 0;
}
```

It should return 1 in RSA_Sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DoVerify(PUBKEY_FILENAME, &info, "Hello.txt.sign");
```

This should be:

```
DoVerify(PUBKEY_FILENAME, &info, "Hello.txt");
```

The signature itself is being passed through the `&info` parameter. The last parameter is supposed to be the actual thing signed, not the signature.

Comment: That's when I need a third eye. you're totally right. and I don't know why I was passing the signature. Thank you

Comment: The signature verification code needs three things: the public key, the signature, and the thing signed. Your `DoVerify` function takes three parameters. If you wanted to, you could easily modify it to take the signature by filename as well.

Comment: Actually this was the "beta version" of my application. you're right in my updated version I'm reading the signature from file. 
thanks for your valuable note.